# Apache/Lion not serving up site in local testing environment

Tags: apache-2.2, php, virtualhost

Originally posted this over at superuser...

Ive configured Apache for Name-based Virtual Hosting but I can't seem to get a local site to show in my browser. Is my httpd.conf misconfigured? Here's the sanitized version:

```
#
# Use Name-based Virual Hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *.:80

#
#Set up permissions for VirtualHosts in ~/Sites
#
<Directory "/Users/myusername/Sites">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

# For http://localhost in the OSX default location
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/Documents
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName thewebsite.local
    CustomLog "/Users/myusername/Sites/logs/thewebsite.local-access_log" combined
    ErrorLog "/Users/myusername/Sites/logs/thewebsite.local-error_log"
    DocumentRoot "/Users/myusername/Sites/thewebsite.local"
</VirtualHost>
```

And my etc/hosts

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       thewebsite.local
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache searches the vhost list from top to bottom and will deliver content from the first virtual host that matches the host header or default whichever comes first. In your configuration the default virtual host is listed first so it's content gets delivered. Put your default site at the end or at least after sites whose content you want delivered.

The  `NameVirtualHost` directive is usually `NameVirtualHost *:80`. It's generally not a great idea to use .local as it's use by mDNS etc and can get in the way.

Comment: When I change my .conf file it navigates to the `/Library/WebServer/Documents` folder now.